# How to detect a property value in enmap in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I have a discord bot, and I have a configuration enmap for each server. I have one property called "welcomer" and I want to do if welcomer = true, execute the event guildMemberAdd and Remove, and if welcomer = false, don't execute them.

I'm using enmap, so I tried the hasProp, the get, and some other stuff. But it doesn't work. I'll leave my actual code of the settings and the guildMemberAdd below.

defaultSettings.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: "c!",
  modLogChannel: "mod-log",
  modRole: "Moderator",
  adminRole: "Administrator",
  welcomer: true,
  logChannel: "welcome",
  welcomeMessage:
    "Hello %user!\nWelcome to the official %server server!\nPlease take a look at the server rules, and feel free to get to know the other members.\nThis server now has %total users",
  goodbyeMessage:
    "Goodbye, %user\n Sad, but true, one user left the server :(.\n Now, %server have %total users."
};
```

guildMemberAdd.js:

```js
const config = require("../../config.json");
const vars = require("../../variables.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const defaultSettings = require("../../defaultSettings.js");
const Enmap = require("enmap");

module.exports = async (client, member) => {
  client.configs.ensure(member.guild.id, defaultSettings);
  if(client.configs.hasProp(message.guild.id, true, "welcomer")) {
  var welcomeMessage = client.configs.get(member.guild.id, "welcomeMessage");
  if(welcomeMessage.includes("%user")) {
  welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage.replace(/%user/g, member.user);
}
  if(welcomeMessage.includes("%server")) {
  welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage.replace(/%server/g, member.guild.name);
}
  if(welcomeMessage.includes("%total")) {
  welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage.replace(/%total/g, member.guild.memberCount);
}

  let welcomemsg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Hello! :wave:`)
    .setDescription(welcomeMessage)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
    .setColor(vars.good)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`ID: ${member.user.id}`, member.user.avatarURL);

  member.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === client.configs.get(member.guild.id, "logChannel")).send(welcomemsg);
} else {
  return;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enmap.get()`](https://enmap.evie.dev/api#Enmap+get) to retrieve a property of an object in the Enmap using the syntax shown here:

```js
client.configs.ensure(member.guild.id, defaultSettings);

if (client.configs.get(member.guild.id, 'welcomer') === true) { // If 'fetchAll' is false,
  ...                                                           // Enmap.get() will return a
}                                                               // Promise, changing this.
```